# How to make a "world" type thing in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I dont really know exactly how to explain my issue so i will do my best. I'm looking to make an html game with javascript. I want to know how to setup an environment that has a big "world" but what you can see is only a small part of it as you move around. If you have ever played agar.io thats what i mean. Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: That is a question for Google. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions that derive from specific code.

Comment: With a bunch of code. You store data, figure out what region to show, look up the data that should appear.

Comment: I believe what you're talking about is *Frustum culling*. Good luck on your google adventure!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a comment for this but i can't, not enough reputation. Anyway, you could have a look at http://phaser.io. It's a game framework which makes use of HTML5's new features and JavaScript for the functionality, if you follow some tutorials on YouTube and/or Google. you should find some really good examples.

Good luck in your ventures.